# Xcode 4.5.2 keeps crashing on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, crash, osx-lion

I have been using Xcode with mac os x lion and I kept getting an error when trying to test my app on my ios device. I formatted my computer and upgraded to mountain lion and revoked all the apple developer certificates and provisions and started from scratch.

Now I do not get an error anymore but when I click run Xcode crashes. I have seen other people having the same issue. I tried installing the tools in Xcode and reinstalling Xcode but nothing seems to work. I even tried other apps. Xcode even crashes when I look at the preferences or just randomly but it is unusable. I have tried what people have suggested but I think maybe its the update to Mountain Lion.

Anybody have any thoughts on what I can do to fix it ? Thanks guys and Ill post the Xcode error below.

---

```
Process:         Xcode [3082]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.5.2 (1847)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1847000000000000~5
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 11823664
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [120]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-11-11 23:59:26.948 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8 (12A239)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          12182 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           7
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  2713 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      08010D4F-F690-41D3-BFD3-D1ECE072975C

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007fff50fe0ff8

VM Regions Near 0x7fff50fe0ff8:
    MALLOC_SMALL           00007fb59e800000-00007fb59f800000 [ 16.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> STACK GUARD            00007fff4d7e1000-00007fff50fe1000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 0
    Stack                  00007fff50fe1000-00007fff517e1000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 0

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G2008a
objc[3082]: garbage collection is ON
Performing @selector(performRunAction:) from sender IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton 0x4023116a0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x000000011621a96e -[NSClipView(IBWorkaround12332156) ibSwizzledNSClipViewWorkaround12332156UpdateConstraints] + 21
1   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x000000011621a9fc -[NSClipView(IBWorkaround12332156) ibSwizzledNSClipViewWorkaround12332156UpdateConstraints] + 163
2   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x000000011621a9fc -[NSClipView(IBWorkaround12332156) ibSwizzledNSClipViewWorkaround12332156UpdateConstraints] + 163
3   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x000000011621a9fc -[NSClipView(IBWorkaround12332156) ibSwizzledNSClipViewWorkaround12332156UpdateConstraints] + 163
4   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration    0x000000011621a9fc -[NSClipView(IBWorkaround12332156) ibSwizzledNSClipViewWorkaround12332156UpdateConstraints] + 163
5   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm encountering the same exact issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where multiple instances of XCode were running in the background, causing XCode crashes. I'm not sure if this will help or not, but you can try the following in a terminal.

```
alias findp="ps -axww | grep $*"
```

this is just some shorthand.

see what this does.

```
findp Xcode
```

If you have a huge list of instances returning for that call, when you are not actually running Xcode, then it means you have a heap of orphaned background xcode processes. The simulator will also hold onto xcode instances, so you'll need to close that as well.

Anyway, if you have the problem i had, you'll see repsones along the lines of

```
 7645 ??         0:00.12 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/accountsd
```

you can then kill these with

```
kill -9 7645
```

Not sure if that will help you or not, but it has saved me many times when xcode has played silly buggers with me.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the comment. I gave it a try and it doesnt seem to have made a difference. It still keeps crashing. I tried again and it crashed when I click run and when I clicked to fix the retina display warning. I cant seem to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I know it isn't the ideal solution, but what I found to work for me was to download the iOS 5.0 and 5.1 SDKs to run testing through the simulator (yes, I know this creates an issue with not being able to run tests through the current simulator...) but I can run my app just fine on my provisioned iPhone device for testing in iOS 6.0

It seems that the 6.0 simulator is the culprit in causing this particular crash. Also, if you have the same setup as I do, then you will need to be aware that you will need to stop the application before attempting to run it again, or it will result in a crash. Also, if you are running a simulator (5.1 or 5.0) then you will need to be sure that you not only stop your application, but close the simulator completely down. Otherwise, this may result in another crash.

All of the failures that I have encountered through my current environment's installation of XCode 4.5.2 have resulted in the exact same error message you received above.

Hope this helps!

-d3v1lman1337